# PHP Day (l) in While Loop not showing proper day

Tags: php

I getting data from database and showing those in table. 
getting dates between selected date range which working properly.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

 $date = $row['tt_date']; //get dates from table column

echo $date; // showing proper values

}
```

when i added

```
echo date('l', strtotime( $date));
```

or

```
 echo date('l',$date);
```

It keep showing **Thursday** for all the data retrieving from table;

It suppose to show proper day for the retrieve date.

Comment: Which date you are getting from table?

Comment: Dates of 1 week period @b0s3

Comment: `date` function 2nd parameter should be a timestamp. `strtotime` needs proper date format. Show your `echo $date; ` output.

Comment: @lolka_bolka , echo $date; 

2015.08.31 | 2015.08.31 | 2015.09.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the OP comment, it seems, the `$date` variable holds more than one date, so OP need to explode that string, and change the `.` character to `-` in the loop:

```
    $date = '2015.08.31 | 2015.08.31 | 2015.09.02';
    echo $date;
    //Will output 2015.08.31 | 2015.08.31 | 2015.09.02
    //So now here, you need to explode this string with " | "
    $datesArray = explode(" | ", $date);
    var_dump($datesArray);
    //The output is:
    //array (size=3)
    //  0 => string '2015.08.31' (length=10)
    //  1 => string '2015.08.31' (length=10)
    //  2 => string '2015.09.02' (length=10)
    //Now you need to iterate through on this array
    foreach ($datesArray as $dateString) {
        //You need to replace the "." character to "-" for the strtotime function
        echo date('l', strtotime( str_replace('.','-',$dateString))) ."<br>\n";
    }
    //Output is:
    //Monday
    //Monday
    //Wednesday
    //I've checked the calendar, and it's correct
```